# get multiple tag values, except one

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, tags, lxml

I am trying to get the tag value from multiple identical tags, except one particular one which I want to ignore. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="film5.1">
    <provider>studiocanal</provider>
    <language>en-GB</language>
    <video>
        <crew>
            <crew_member billing="top">
                <display_name>John Doe</display_name>
                <roles>
                    <role>Director</role>
                    <role>Screenwriter</role>
                </roles>
            </crew_member>
            <crew_member billing="ordered">
                <display_name>Harry Smith</display_name>
                <roles>
                    <role>Screenwriter</role>
                </roles>
            </crew_member>
            <crew_member billing="ordered">
                <display_name>Jane Doe</display_name>
                <roles>
                    <role>Screenwriter</role>
                </roles>
            </crew_member>
            <crew_member billing="ordered">
                <display_name>Mr. Kimbley</display_name>
                <roles>
                    <role>Producer</role>
                </roles>
            </crew_member>
        </crew>
    </video>
</package>
```

I need to get the  values ignoring the 2nd one and put it in a list, I only want to get the first  value from the John Doe section. I can't seem to get it to work.
This is my current code, which creates and fills the list, but I have 5 roles, but only want 4, skipping the 2nd one. Heres my current code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(templateXml)
crewList2 = []
for element in root.xpath('//video/crew/crew_member/roles/role'):
    crewList2.append( element )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
crewList2 = []
for element in tree.xpath('//video/crew/crew_member/roles'):
    role = element.xpath('.//role[1]')
    if role:
        crewList2.append(role[0].text)

print crewList2
```

prints:

```
['Director', 'Screenwriter', 'Screenwriter', 'Producer']
```

Comment: I am trying to apply the above code, but it's passing if role: so the crewList2.append(role[0].text) never gets executed.

Comment: Are you sure then that your code was working and printing 5-len list?

Comment: With namespaces `{'it': 'http://apple.com/itunes/importer'}`, a single xpath of `//it:video/it:crew/it:crew_member/it:roles/it:role[1]/text()` will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using one XPath expression, namespace registration and `lxml.etree.tostring(..., method="text")`:

```
roles = tree.xpath('//it:video/it:crew/it:crew_member/it:roles/it:role[1]', namespaces={"it": "http://apple.com/itunes/importer"})
crewList2 = [etree.tostring(e, method="text", encoding=unicode).strip() for e in roles]
```